# Php reading line from a php file and group them by order

Tags: php

Hello i have a txt file which contains data like this :

- ABC
- DEF
- ABC
- DEF
- GHI
- ABC
- DEF
- GHI

What i've done is reading the file line by line and generating a big array
which contains all the line

```
    array(7) {

      [0]=>
      string(3) "ABC"
      [1]=>
      string(3) "DEF"
      [2]=>
      string(3) "ABC"
      [3]=>
      string(3) "DEF"
      [4]=>
      string(3) "GHI"
      [5]=>
      string(3) "ABC"
      [6]=>
      string(3) "DEF"
      [7]=>
      string(3) "GHI"
      
      .... big array not only this 7 index 

    }
```

What i need is generating a subarray which takes as data ABC, DEF and GHI

so this array must contain only in this case indexes 2,3,4,5,6,7 because index 2
starts with ABC but we need the order ABC DEF and GHI.
I hope that i'm clearly with my explanation in other words, i need to check this big
array every 3 indexes and if index 0 = ABC

- Index 1 = DEF
- Index 2 = GHI
  push into the empty array
- Index 3 = ABC
- Index 4 = DEF
- Index 5 = GHI
  push into empty array
- Index 6 = ABC  // remove this
- Index 7 = DEF  // remove this
- Index 8 = ABC
- Index 9 = DEF
- Index 10 = GHI

push 8,9,10 to empty array

exc ..

I really hope that i'm explaining in good words so you can understand and try to help me

Thank you

Comment: I just need to figure out how i can start. Every kind of help is appreciate.

Comment: If you want to push, use the foreach loop with an index.

foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)

The key will be the index and the value will be whatever is inside the array.  Use that to build a new array based on filtering out the index position and returned value.

Comment: Can you type what output you want to get? Your explanation is not very clear.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take a [tour] of the site, read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Then come back to your question and reformulate it (preferably with code samples, the provided input and the expected output) in order to get a (useful) answer. Before posting a question, [search](/search) the site and make sure a similar question wasn't already answered. Show what you have tried and where you got stuck to maximize the chances to get help.

Comment: Please clarify the criteria for what should be 1. discarded, 2. pushed to second array, and why?. Also, should the remainder be unique values only? Also, do the index (line) numbers matter? Also, provide a complete sample of expected output, given your input sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1: iterate the array in a for loop, if current element is `ABC`, next is `DEF`, and one after that is `GHI` then add those to the result.

```
<?php

$input = [
  'ABC', //
  'DEF', //
  'GHI', //
  'ABC',
  'DEF',
  'ABC', //
  'DEF', //
  'GHI', //
  'ABC',
  'GHI',
  'DEF',
];

// 1
$result = [];
for($i=0;$i<count($input)-2;$i++) {
  if ($input[$i] === 'ABC' && $input[$i+1] === 'DEF' && $input[$i+2] === 'GHI') {
    $result[] = $input[$i];
    $result[] = $input[$i+1];
    $result[] = $input[$i+2];
  }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Solution 2 is a oneliner bonus - different approach:
Load this array into one long string, search how many times in that string `ABCDEFGHI` can be found. Repeat this string that many times and load it back to the array in 3 character chunks:

```
// 2
$result = str_split(str_repeat('ABCDEFGHI', substr_count(implode('', $input), 'ABCDEFGHI')), 3);

var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "ABC"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "DEF"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "GHI"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "ABC"
  [4]=>
  string(3) "DEF"
  [5]=>
  string(3) "GHI"
}
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "ABC"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "DEF"
  [2]=>
  string(3) "GHI"
  [3]=>
  string(3) "ABC"
  [4]=>
  string(3) "DEF"
  [5]=>
  string(3) "GHI"
}
```